# how to set java parameters for Confluent distribution kafka jvm?

Tags: confluent-platform

the confluent installation guide doesnt say how to modify jvm options.
for example, things like tuning the GC, enabling jmx etc.

Am i supposed to add an environment variable? if so which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find environment variables from confluent bin directory:

```
$ grep jmx confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-run-class 
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT "
```

So use envs like KAFKA_JMX_OPTS for JMX settings, or KAFKA_OPTS for generic JVM settings.